# Twitter API - Get number of followers of followers

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, rate-limiting

I'm trying to get the number of followers of each follower for a specific account (with the goal of finding the most influencial followers).  I'm using Tweepy in Python but I am running into the API rate limits and I can only get the number of followers for 5 followers before I am cut off. The account I'm looking at has about 2000 followers.  Is there any way to get around this?

my code snippet is

```
ids = api.followers_ids(account_name)
for id in ids:
    more = api.followers_ids(id)
    print len(more)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to get all user followers in order to count them. Use `followers_count` property. E.g.:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(..., ...)
auth.set_access_token(..., ...)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="twitter").items():
    print user.screen_name, user.followers_count
```

Prints:

```
...
pizzerialoso 0
Mario98Y 0
sumankumarjana 1
realattorneylaw 3056
JaluSeptyan 10
andhita_khanza 18
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is better but I'm still getting cut-off, but still getting more info.

Answer (score 2):

This works. However, I have an alternate solution which can get specific user based quantitative info such as count of followers, statuses etc.

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(..., ...)
auth.set_access_token(..., ...)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

follower_count = api.get_user('twitter').followers_count
print(follower_count)
```