# Grabbing a specific value from a webpage using LXML

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to grab a value from a page using LXML and Python.

I followed some basic examples which worked. But I'm struggling to get the text from quite a complex (to me at least) web page.

I want to grab the number of followers from this page:
http://twitter.com/aberdeencc

I want the **exact** value of followers which (at the time of writing is 10,623 - not the displayed 10.6K. The exact value is just shown as a tooltip-style mouseover.

Looking at the page code it is in this section:

```
<a class="ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-openSignupDialog js-nonNavigable u-textUserColor" data-nav="followers" 
   href="/AberdeenCC/followers" data-original-title="10,623 Followers">
       <span class="ProfileNav-label">Followers</span>
       <span class="ProfileNav-value" data-is-compact="true">10.6K</span>
</a>
```

The code I have is

```
from lxml import html

import requests

page = requests.get('http://twitter.com/aberdeencc')

tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

followers = tree.xpath('//span[@class="ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link 

u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-openSignupDialog js-nonNavigable 

u-textUserColor"]/text()')

print 'Followers: ', followers
```

But that returns an empty list.

(I know a don't need a list for a single value, but I'm working from existing code)

Thanks for any pointers you can give

Watty

Comment: The tag is "a", but your xpath is for "span".

Comment: Why don't you use the API? See this question and answers for usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450952/twitter-api-get-number-of-followers-of-followers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rely on the `data-nav` attribute instead and get the value of the `title` attribute:

```
from lxml import html
import requests


page = requests.get('http://twitter.com/aberdeencc')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

followers = tree.xpath('//a[@data-nav="followers"]/@title')
print 'Followers: ', followers
```

Prints:

```
Followers:  ['10,623 Followers']
```

In order, to exract the actual number from the `followers`, you can use a regular expression and then parse the string to `int` using [`locale.atoi()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.atoi):

```
import locale
import re
from lxml import html
import requests


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

page = requests.get('http://twitter.com/aberdeencc')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

followers = tree.xpath('//a[@data-nav="followers"]/@title')[0]
followers = re.match(r'^([0-9,]+)\sFollowers$', followers).group(1)
followers = locale.atoi(followers)

print 'Followers:', int(followers)
```

Prints:

```
Followers: 10623
```

---

Besides, twitter provides an [API](https://dev.twitter.com/) which you can use through the python interface, there are multiple options to choose from:

- [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)
- [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter)
- [twitter](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter)

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks. Very helpful. I did look at the Twitter API - and have used it a little with the Twiiter library. Looking at the documentation, it looked like I could get the details of all the followers, but not a simple count back (without pulling down all of the followers; details, paging through them then counting which seemed pretty inefficient compared to just quickly grabbing the figure I needed.

Comment: @Watty62 yeah, brief search shows that the actual followers count is missing from the API, it needs a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get("https://twitter.com/aberdeencc")
>>> doc = etree.HTML(page.text)
>>> doc.xpath('//a[@data-nav="followers"]/@title')
['10,623 Followers']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise agains using `xpath` in that particular case. I think the [CSS selector API](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) is better suited for that case. This should work:

```
followers = tree.cssselect("a.ProfileNav-stat")[0].attrib["data-original-title"]
# followers = '10,623 Followers'
```

This method requires `cssselect` to be installed.